# How do you find open transactions on Windows Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

In SQL Server 2008 R2 you can use the following to find all open transactions when debugging deadlocks:

```
DBCC OPENTRAN
```

However that functionality is not available in Windows Azure SQL Database; it instead throws the errors:

```
"DBCC command 'OPENTRAN' is not supported in this version of SQL Server."
```

The `sp_who2` stored procedure doesn't exist either.

What is the correct query for getting all open transactions within the Azure version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the DMVs instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_tran_database_transactions

SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this script: Explained all require cases.

```
SELECT 
     tdt.transaction_id
     ,tst.session_id
     ,tdt.database_transaction_begin_time
     ,CASE tdt.database_transaction_type
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Read/write transaction'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Read only transaction'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'System transaction'
      END transaction_type
     ,CASE tdt.database_transaction_state
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Transaction not initialized'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Transaction has not generated by any log'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Transaction has generated by log'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Transaction Prepared'
    WHEN 10 THEN 'Transaction Committed'
    WHEN 11 THEN 'Transaction Rolled back'
    WHEN 12 THEN 'Transaction committed and log generated'
     END transaction_state     
FROM sys.dm_tran_database_transactions tdt
INNER JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions tst
  ON tst.transaction_id = tdt.transaction_id
```

Answer (score 0):

dbcc opentran is supported in SQL DB v12. Please upgrade your server. Te other option is sys.dm_tran_active_transactions