# DBCC OpenTran in Sql Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-server

In On Premise SQL Server we have used `DBCC OpenTran` but we have found that `DBCC OpenTran` is not available in Azure. What is the alternative for this?

Comment: As per Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-opentran-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), `DBCC OpenTran` is supported in Azure SQL database also. If it doesnot work, try this query `SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran = 1`

Comment: Take a look at DMVs in the sys.dm_tran_* space. E.g. `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`.

Comment: Its always shows `No active open transactions.`

Comment: Results will be displayed only if there is an active transaction that exists in the log. Otherwise, it will show message like No active open transactions.

Comment: You can find the similar question and related answers here:
["How do you find open transactions on Windows Azure SQL Database?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404529/how-do-you-find-open-transactions-on-windows-azure-sql-database)

Comment: @Aswin there is open transaction that's why I said its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-opentran-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) , `DBCC OpenTran` is supported in Azure SQL database. If it does not work, try using sys views like **sys.dm_exec_sessions**, **sys.sysprocesses** .

- `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions where open_transaction_count=1;`
- `SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran = 1`

**Query:**

The following query obtains active transaction information for the current database using  dbcc Opentran , **sys.sysprocesses** view, **sys.dm_exec_sessions** view.

```
CREATE TABLE T1(Col1 INT, Col2 CHAR(3));  
GO  
BEGIN TRAN  
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (101, 'abc'); 
GO  
DBCC OPENTRAN;  
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran = 1;
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions where open_transaction_count=1;
ROLLBACK TRAN;  
GO  
DROP TABLE T1;  
GO
```

**Result:**

result of **DBCC OPENTRAN**:
[image]

result of **sys.sysprocesses** view:
[image]

result of **sys.dm_exec_sessions** view:
[image]

Refer the Microsoft document [sys.dm_exec_sessions T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)  for additional information.